# Sending Notification's with time taken from Sql database

Tags: java, android

I need small help , as title say's i need to send notification to specific time saved in sql (Room) database.I tryed with alarmManager and Broadcast reciver but i cant figure out how to get time from database while app is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start a background service, like `WorkManager`, which you can make it `Periodic` (repeat every 15 minutes minimum sported time). It will run even if your cellphone restarts. WorkManager is pretty easy to be configured and used.

Example:

```
class MyBackgroundWorker extends Worker {
  public MyBackgroundWorker(Context context, WorkParameters workParameters){
     super(context, workParameters);
   }

  @Override
  Result doWork(){
    //make room request here
    //after selection is successful schedule your alarm manager notification here
  }
}
```

Now, how to start it:

On the moment you need it:

```
WorkManager.getInstance(myContext).enqueue(OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>()
        .build());

//or you can choose periodic requests.
```

[Please refer to the documentation for more](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics).

Comment: thanks on answer can you just help me out....how can i aces Room database from class or worker class?..

Comment: you need an instance of the `Dao` you are working with. You can use Dependency Injection for this. 

`ClockDao dao = YourApplication.getDao()` in the `doWork` method